# XAMPP: Couldn't start Apache (Windows 10)

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm using XAMPP, and I can start Apache, but, MySQL ([phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin)) start!

When I start, I get this error;

```
10:07:49 [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:07:49 [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
10:07:49 [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:07:49 [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:07:49 [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:07:49 [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
10:07:49 [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

I search on it, and, change the port of Apache in Config -> Service and Port setting. I have;

```
Service name: Apache 2.4
Main port: 122
SSL port: 444
```

I also uninstall Skype (Windows 8/10/Metro version). Nothing is working. In the *httpd.conf* file I have;

```
Listen 122
ServerName localhost:122
```

I start it via `apache_start.bat` and get;

```
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:445
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:445
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

**Please note that all the *log* files don’t exists!**
**Skype is uninstalled.**

Comment: Did you checked if the port is blocked?

Comment: Try running as administrator as well

Comment: Are you running skype when you are trying to enable apache? If so change skype settings.

Comment: You cannot have `localhost:80` and listen to port `122`. Choose which port to listen to.

Comment: Ok, I made some modification : @Rizier123 -> I check but I'm not sure if it's the good way.   @Will-Campbell -> Yes, but nothing more.    @iSaumya -> Skype is not on my computer. @Lorenz-Meyer -> I have now `Listen 122` and `ServerName localhost:122`

Comment: skype was the culprit in my case. @iSaumya thanks!

Comment: @L4reds you are welcome :)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

**Update: 15th May, 2018:**

The latest Windows 10 update (re-)activated the **World Wide Web Publishing Service** (in German: **WWW-Publishingdienst**). This might depend on the options you select during the configuration of the update you can make afterwards.

**Update: 4th August, 2015:**

If you have done clean installation of Windows 10, you may not have the **Word Wide Web Publishing Service**. In that case, simple WAMP/XAMPP installation should work fine.

If it doesn't, try installing **[Visual C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)** and then re-install WAMP/XAMPP.

---

I was facing a similar problem with WAMP. In Windows 10 TP, the **Word Wide Web Publishing Service** comes pre-installed. This is related to IIS and you can remove it if you don't need it.

This blocks the port `80`, making Apache act weirdly. You can do the following and try again.

- Go to Start, type in **services.msc**
- Scroll down in the Services window to find the **World Wide Web Publishing Service**.
- Right click on it and select **Stop**.

This should make port **80** free and restarting WAMP/XAMPP should get you up and running!

There are other ways to do fix this. See *[Make WAMP Work On Windows 10](http://praveenpuglia.com/make-wamp-work-on-windows-10-technical-preview/)*.

Comment: Im sure this can resolve my problem. But I have a problem... I have uninstall Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: Just had the same problem after the free upgrade today. Thanks!

Comment: What if I don't have "World Wide Web Publishing Service" as a service listed?

Comment: You should probably look for skype. or in general, run a `netstat -n` to see if the port 80 is blocked. Also, it could be because of VC++ not being installed. try that.

Comment: The _name_ of the service is **W3SVC** while the _description_ is **World Wide Web Publishing Service**. I initially did not think I had the service because I was not seeing the service described when sorting by name.

Comment: Does it list with the name W3SVC when you open services.msc ?

Comment: Yea, I had this problem as well, it kept telling me "A process witha PID of 4 is using port 80" when I checked it, the process name was "System". I kept thinking I could mess up my PC if i tried stopping this process. But this worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Stepping in to 1) upvote your answer and 2) thank you.

Comment: what does installing VC++ Redist. do to resolve the issue?  That seems like it might work since W3SVC doesn't exist on my clean install of Win10.  I'd need the x64 bit version, but do I need VSU4\vcredist_arm.exe as well?

Comment: it looks like they are already installed so I guess this solution won't work for me.

Comment: @mtpultz - WAMPServer website mentions it as must have when you try to download it. Guessing some libraries are required for apache to run properly. May be XAMPP website doesn't list it assuming it would be installed by default.

Comment: For those outthere using the Uniform server Z (which is great!), I can confirm this working for that server too.

Comment: @PraveenPuglia hum.. interessant comment, work to me! i try remove file "ntoskrnl.exe" is a cause port 4 ... much google search say virus... nice services to stop is work lol.. thanks bro

Comment: This whole thing is another Windows 10 fail! - I eventually gave up. I couldn't get XAMPP plus MySQL Workbench working together on Win 10, even though it was fine on Win7. I switched over to Local (by Flywheel) instead. Flywheel has its own wheelhouse of issues, but one benefit is that SSL works locally on Local (Flywheel) :-) But Local requires workarounds if you do not use a standard installation for WordPress (eg. if WP is installed in its own directory), and updating from v3 to v5 broke all sites/corrupted databases. Afraid to update again, I *may* retry XAMPP.. UGH. Or switch to Mac

Answer (score 40):

Solving this problem is easy:

1. Open a command prompt with administrator privileges

   - Find "cmd", right-click on it, then select "Administrator".
2. In the prompt, type `net stop W3SVC` and Enter.

You can now click in WAMPP and restart all services. Open your browser and navigate to "localhost".

If you need to start W3SVC again,

1. Open a command prompt with administrator privileges
2. In the prompt, type `net start W3SVC` and Enter.

Comment: On the released version of Windows 10, I get "System error 3 has occurred. Access is denied."

Comment: You need be administrator.  Try again.

Comment: Yep, thanks DIANGELISJ.  In Windows 10, a right click on cmd and then your instructions above, then a right click on httpd.exe and I got Apache working again. The httpd.exe box is a black blank, but Apache works.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 10 using XAMPP.  After each restart I would have to go to the XAMPP control panel and reinstall and start the Apache and MySQL services again.  Running the XAMPP control panel as administrator seems to have cured it, thanks!

Comment: this is the correct answer, all you need to do is to shut down IIS, and then start xampp. Control-Panel - Admin - Internet Information Services - "Stop" That's it. Easy as pie.  ( same thing as above, just through interfaces.)

Answer (score 17):

I found a way to solve this problem:

1. If you are using Skype as well, uncheck the field stating to use ports 80 and 443 (Extra -> Settings -> Advanced -> Connections -> Uncheck Port 80 and 443)
2. Restart Skype and XAMPP.

If this does not work,

1. Go to Start and type "services.msc"
2. Locate "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
3. Right-click on that entry, select "Stop", then restart XAMPP.

If that did not work and "World Wide Web Publishing Service" was not available,

1. Go to the Control Panel, navigate to "Uninstall Programs", then "Turn on/off Windows features"
2. Locate "Internet Information Services"
3. Click the checkbox and hit "OK".
4. Restart, then repeat the second approach (services.msc)

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is already answered. Maybe it could help someone ese (:

Comment: Your answer could not help me , i figured out my own solution . Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Brilliant! It was just Skype blocking Apache! My favourite part of the process: after turning off Skype's ports 80 & 443, I had to quit out of Skype. A warning came up saying (paraphrased) "If you quit Skype you won't be able to use it." Well, duh!

Answer (score 16):

You can change the port of Apache:

1. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.
2. Find by combination Ctrl+F line #Listen 12.34.56.78:80 and change the 80 to any you like for example 81
3. The same with Listen 80 change to 81
4. The same with ServerName localhost:80 change to 81.
5. Go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts and change 80 to 81

NameVirtualHost *:80 here

VirtualHost *:80 and here (two times)

6. Restart Apache

To enter your web page, type: http://localhost:81/index.html

Comment: I will recomend this one

Comment: Does changing commented line really make sense ? (step 2 `#Listen 12.34.56.78:80`)

Comment: easy peasy, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type `regedit`.
2. Go to

   ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP
   ```

   Change the value of `Start` to 4, which means disabled.
3. Reboot your computer.

Comment: The Windows 10 "November Upgrade" caused my issue - all had worked before on the older version of Win 10.  I didn't have W3svc running or Skype.  *This* solution did the trick!  Thanks @Do Nhu Vy!

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this issue with mine as well, but I had to change a couple of things. I require that on my Windows 10 machine I keep my C# and Visual Studio development environment, so I didn't want to tinker with any services. All I had to do was download the latest version of XAMPP and change the listening ports for 80 and 443. They were located in two files:

`C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

```
Listen 122
ServerName localhost:122
```

`C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`

```
Listen 444
```

Changing the above from port 80 to 122 and 443 to 444 allowed me to have Apache run and serve pages while keeping everything else the same for my [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) development. Hopefully this helps someone out there.  In the end this is a very simple fix.

Direct your browser to: `http://localhost:122`

Comment: I think this is the easiest and simplest way. Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 because shutting down .NET Services is definitely no option for me. Of course I want to run IIS and Apache at the same time!

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything listed in the answers here but none of them worked.

Then all I did was to re-start XAMPP with administrator rights by:

> Start menu - right click on XAMPP - select run as administartor

It worked. It is that simple.

I uninstalled IIS services, stopped WWW services, changed ports back to 80, blocked all apache and mysql connections from windows 10 firewall, but yes it still works!

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem, but the previous solutions leads us to change the port instead of getting the exact solution. I've searched about the ports of simple HTTP & HTTPS Protocols and found.

**If another application is already running, the HTTP or HTTPS ports on the local machine, we'll get this problem obviously just because of those ports already in use and in a busy state**.

That's why after changing the port number it was working.
But instead of changing the port in the XAMPP server, I've used the following methods and it works for me.

Here's the following step which I've got during this fix up.

1. Error which I got in XAMPP Server application.

   [image: XAMPP Server Error]
2. At the top corner there's a button named **Netstat**.
   It's very useful for looking up the running ports on the system.

   [image: Netstat button]
3. This is the Netstat application where I found an application already running and using the port number 443. In my case, it was **vmware-hostd.exe**. Your might be a different application. Try to search for port 80 (HTTP) or port 443 (HTTPS).

   [image: Netstat application opened]
4. I just opened the Windows [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), selected that application **vmware-hostd.exe**, and killed the process by using the **End Process** button. I've killed that process which was used port 443. And this application wasn't needed at the moment.

   [image: Opened task manager and kill that application]
5. After killing the application in Windows Task Manager, Apache is now available at the moment. Here's the proof.

   [image: Apache working]

---

**NOTE:** *If you found any kind of application which is used the **HTTP** or **HTTPS** ports means port **80** or port **443** and the application isn't important or not vital then only kill the process of that application.

Otherwise, there isn't any need to follow these steps. Then you need to consider to change the port of your XAMPP application as stated in the previous answers.*

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are many options. The answer depends on your Windows installation. Here is my experience when having the same problem in a Windows 10 fresh install and fix the issue with the following step:

1. Install [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
2. Open XAMPP and select configure in the Apache service
3. Change the port 80 to 9000 or 81 or whatever you want in file *httpd.conf* on the line `Listen 80`
4. Change the port on httpd-ssl.conf and change `Listen 443` to `Listen 441`
5. Restart XAMPP and start the Apache service. It works for me.

*Note*: I'm using XAMPP version 5.6.15 and XAMPP Control Panel version 3.2.2.

Comment: Good catch - ensure the http and https ports are not in conflict

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Change the port number which port are available in your system By following ways**

**1. First open the Apache “httpd.conf” file:**

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

to

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

**2. Open httpd-ssl.conf:**

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

to

```
Listen 441
<VirtualHost _default_:441>
```

**3. Follow the trick. Now “Start” Apache and if everything goes well, your Apache server should start up.**

Comment: thx , worked for me , but now i cant start that sql server ;), but thx

Answer (score 2):

After playing around, really all you have to do is change two lines in the *httpd.conf* file:

Change *"Listen 80"* to *"Listen 122"* (or anything else you want)

and

*"ServerName Localhost:80"* to *"Localhost:122"* (or the port you changed above)

Then it all should fire right up :P

Answer (score 2):

The *World Wide Web Publishing* service was not the only one responsible in my case.

I have IIS installed, so I had to stop the whole HTTP service.

These are the commands that I've executed in CMD (as administrator):

```
net stop W3SVC
net stop http
```

Answer (score 1):

- Go to the start menu, and type *Turn Windows features on or off*
- Uncheck *Internet Information Services*
- Press <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by default IIS (Microsoft, .NET, etc.) is installed.

- Go to Control Panel
- *Turn Windows features on or off...*
- Under (IIS) Internet Information Services, uncheck the (WWWS) world wide web services.
- Click OK.

This could be a permanent solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

This advice was great. I had the same problem, but my solution was different, because I was so stupid, that I have renamed directory where XAMPP was located and since I had installed a lot of another programs I couldn't rename it back.

In my case there was original directory **C:\Programs\Xampp** and renamed it to **C:\PROGRAMS_\Xampp** and that was the mistake.

The solution was to find all references on **C:\Programs** and rename them **C:\PROGRAMS_** in the XAMPP directory, because for some reason during the installation it writes absolute paths, not relative. Of course, there are some references in the registry too.

Comment: This seems to be a very specific case and does not seem to correspond with the scenario of the question.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I think it may help someone, because I was facing the same situation (had fresh windodw 10) and the error was the same, so maybe this is not exactly the same scenario, byt I think someone colud find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a matter of making port 80 available for your Apache service.
The way I solved the problem was:

1. On Windows 10, right click the start button and select *Run*
2. Type *services.msc* and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
3. Find and right click *World wide web publishing service*
4. Select *Properties*
5. Change the *Startup type* value to *Automatic (Delayed Start)*
6. Restart your computer.

There you have it. All is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a simple case of removing IIS because Windows 10 comes with IIS (Internet Information Service) pre installed - that conflicts with XAMPP because these both servers try to use the port 80. If you don't want to use IIS and keep using XAMPP

1. Go to run/search in Windows 10
2. Search for 'optional features'
3. On that list untick *Internet Information Service* (IIS)

Then *restart*.

Answer (score 1):

That was simple for me!

Try to run the XAMPP Control Panel as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the above solutions. But it was not working in any way.

Finally, I just **uninstalled** XAMPP and **installed it again**. Then it worked for me.

Now I am able to **run the server** on any port (including 80).

Answer (score 1):

**I found that running apache_start in gave me the exact error and on which line it was.**

My error was that I left a space in between *localhost:* and the port.

Comment: What is "running apache_start in"? For example, is a word missing?

Comment: Copy-paste works better than typing (unless of course [GNOME is used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188960) - avoid [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) at all cost).

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), some of its services may block the port which XAMPP needs. I solved my problem by disabling *[SQL Server Reporting Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services)* and now Apache starts without any problems.

Just open the `services.msc`, scroll down, and find *SQL Server Reporting Services*. Right click on it and click <kbd>Stop</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- Open the XAMMP Control Panel
- Open Apache Config, and then select the Apache - xammp- configuration file
- Search for "Port 443", and then change it to some other port, let’s say 4433
- Then restart.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your PHP installation works.

Check which *php.ini* file you are running in Apache's configuration and use it to run php.exe...

Answer (score 1):

You may just have updated your Windows to *Version 1903 (OS Build:18362.239)* *or* have changed user passwords. *Despite having eliminated all port conflicts*, I still kept getting the messages described by the OP at the very start of this post.

In the end I cured it by upgrading to XAMPP to 7.3.7. (When forced to reinstall, you might as well upgrade at the same time!)

But the problem reoccurred when I again went to change the 'root' user password.

The console error messages were masking the fact that table **mysql.user** was corrupt.

Check file *mysql_error.log*. If you are seeing **Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Index for table 'user' is corrupt; try to repair it**, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128891/how-repair-corrupt-xampp-mysql-user-table).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I solved it by uninstalling [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) server.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash script which copies the backup files and deletes the log file to fix this problem :

## Copy this script to a file in notepad save it with .sh extension and run it using ./yourfilename.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
src_folder="C:/xampp/mysql/backup/mysql"
dest_folder="C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql"
regex_to_match="aria_log\..+"
search_folder="C:/xampp/mysql/data"

cp -rf $src_folder/* $dest_folder
echo "Xampp7 backup file's copied from $src_folder to $dest_folder"


find "$search_folder" -type f -regex ".*$regex_to_match" -delete

echo "Aria Log File Deleted Successfully!"
echo "Xampp 7 is ready to Go"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).