# Apache won't start after my Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, apache

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. In the Bitnami stack, MySQL is running, but I cannot start Apache as a service when Windows boots up. I have tried using the Manager Tool. I have tried many things, including: changed the Listen port and ServerName to 8888 and later to 8118, turned off Windows Defender, looked at files in Apache's logs directory and errors directory (and found no entries), pressed the Launch Bitnami Webstack button (and just got an empty tab). I have Restarted Windows 10 after each change.

The Application Log in the Manager Tool says:
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 1
Stdout:

Stderr:
Unable to start apache

How do I get Apache to start in Windows10?  Is there some setting in Windows 10 that is critical to allow Apache to function?

Comment: I used the solution posted [here][1], and it worked.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10

Comment: I finally got Apache restarted using the instructions posted by DIANGELISJ in responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10  The right click on cmd is a critical step. After the net stop, I also right clicked on httpd.exe  A blank black box appeared, but Apache restarted.  The Bitnami Manager Tool did not show Apache running (??), but web pages got served up.

Comment: I was getting an error in the event log about httpd not being able to find the apache conf file, but I ran "uninstall Bitnami as a service" and then "installl bitnami as a service" again and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because the IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service is running.

You have to go to start/Execute and write services.msc 
[image]

Right click it and stop it.

Now you should be able to run Apache. You can also disable the start when you right click the service/Propierties

Comment: Task Manager says IIS WWW Publishing Service is not running. I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Rubber Telly Media directed me to the solution:

I had the same problem after upgrade from older Windows 10 to 1903. I couldn't start Apache service, I would get

> error 1067.

I have IIS uninstalled and nothing else blocked port 80 (checked with `CurrPorts`). I had to change:

1. Apache 2.4.38 to Apache 2.4.39
2. PHP 7.3.1 to the latest PHP 7, 7.3.8
3. configure php.ini again (version 7.3.7 didn't solve my problem).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PHP.ini is syntax checked, run it against php.exe in the command prompt window. I had the same issue, it was my version of PHP or php.ini was corrupted...

Answer (score 0):

Start Apache from the command line, from apache bin using the httpd command.
It will give you specific details about the problem.

Comment: it doesn't give my anything useful

Comment: What did it give you?

Comment: Empty! Anyway, I found the issue. The php_openssl.dll is missing somehow after the windows update. I download the same PHP files and replace. Somehow it works. Magic windows.