# Why can't I view my localhost files on Windows 10?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, windows-10

I have recently installed Windows 10. One problem I have encountered is that I can't view localhost files. This is the case for all browsers I use: Chrome, Firefox and not just Edge. In Chrome and Firefox I only see a blank screen whereas Edge gives me an HTTP 404 error message.

I use XAMPP for developing Wordpress sites locally before deploying them to a live server so this is a problem for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if xampp is compatible with 10?

Comment: Glad I saw this - my 'free' upgrade might not be as free as I thought if I get headaches like this.  Did you see this stack? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10