# Windows 10 cannot load page localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I've just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 yesterday.

I have reinstalled XAMPP on my computer, I have an issue is that when click MySQL Admin button it direct me to the localhost/phpmyadmin page, but the page could not load.

Comment: Your answer is here...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to enter these this command using cmd and problem solved, guess there is something wrong with my connection.

```
ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /registerdns

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew

NETSH winsock reset catalog

NETSH int ipv4 reset reset.log

NETSH int ipv6 reset reset.log
```