# "localhost refused to connect" xampp windows 10

Tags: xampp, localhost

Can't start localhost with XAMPP on win10. Local server & SQL runs fine!

Error message Chrome:

"localhost refused to connect"

Explorer:

Can't connect

Thanks

Comment: so is xampp apache started up or not? if it is not started up that might mean it is conflicting with another software that occupied port 80, typically Skype, so try to find out which software another way is to change your port to some thing else

Comment: try to give this link look as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333203/xampp-couldnt-start-apache-windows-10

Comment: I assume that you should disable world wide web service. Start > type "Services" > go to service "world wide web" > right click and stop > restart all services in xampp

Comment: Thx.. There is no such option in Ervices ie  "world wide web"