# localhost on xampp is constantly showing up as blank

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10

Basically, I am coding a website (from raw code can't stand using wordpress) for primary school children and teachers. The function of the website is to teach both children and teachers scratch in simple easy steps. I am in secondary school now going to be in year 10 after summer, and I am thinking of showing this website to my old primary school so the children and teachers can both have a better understanding of scratch.

For this website, I wanted a page where the user can email me from the website so they can suggest improvments for the website or notify me about any bugs. For that, I know I need PHP, I'm fairly new to PHP I know the basics but I am not completely fluent in it. Since I needed PHP I did a little research and downloaded XAMPP for windows (10). I know some of the basics but not much as I only did this last night.

My problem:
Whenever I type in `/localhost/`it just shows up as blank. I've read some places that it may because I messed up somewhere in my installation. Others are saying it is because of my browser (I am using firefox) everyone is being really confusing. I came here for a clear answer. Why is this happening and what can I do fix it?

Comment: Try using `http://localhost`. I just tested `/localhost/` on mine and it worked fine. Make sure that php is indeed started.

Comment: Thanks. But it is still showing up as blank :/

Comment: Are all services running and with a green light? Did you also try restarting your PC after installing? That could do it also. You may also need to run as adminstrator rights. And make sure there's an index.php file in that folder.

Comment: How would I check if my services are running with a green light? And I didn't restart my PC I shutdown my PC, then turned it back on in the morning when I woke up. I've been looking for solutions pretty much all day, but I didn't really understand much.

Comment: Oh and the PHP file is in that folder I know I should do that. Does it have to be index.php? And why do I need to run as adminstrator? I would just like to know so I don't repeat the same mistake in the future.

Comment: You need to start the Xampp control panel and start Apache and PHP if you haven't done that yet. If you haven't, find the shortcut for it, run it and then try again. See also these Q&A's on Stack https://stackoverflow.com/q/27333203/ --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30758894/ and another https://blog.imaginea.com/how-to-make-wampxampp-work-on-windows-10/ - Hope they'll shed a bit of light on all this. *"Does it have to be index.php?"* - I would recommend it, yes.

Comment: *"And why do I need to run as adminstrator?"* - Because it may be blocked by a Firewall or a port and it needs to have full rights. This, in a nutshell.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that you see. I thought you could do localhost with the control panel closed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Also, if you think my question is well written and provides detail please could you give it one point?

Comment: I take it that what I said in one of my last comments helped you solve this, correct? If so, let me write up an answer where you can mark it as solved in order to close the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments; you need to open the Xampp control panel and start the related services such as Apache, as shown in the screenshot.

You may also need to run as administrator rights. Windows 10 does have certain issues about this.

[image]

Comment: Where would I run adminastrator rights? In the control panel?

Comment: @Coderess See the following url http://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-run-programs-as-administrator-in-windows-10-3632744/ it shows you how. Yet, you might not need to do this.

Comment: Oh, ok, got it!

Comment: @Coderess Did you go through the links I left under the question's comment area?

Comment: could it be because I have a 32-bit computer?

Comment: Good news. It took me several times to wrap my head around what you said, but i finally got there in the end. Local host is working perfectly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: That's great @Coderess am glad to hear that everything worked out and thanks for the update, *cheers* and you're welcome.